# Cannot upload Image to a SharePoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working with a Visual WebPart and I want to upload a image from my FileUpload control to a SharePoint list. This is the code I'm using but I can't get it to work, (Title, prodnum, color, etc is working, but not image). I've also installed [SparQube](https://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Picture-Column/).

This is my ListView: 
[image]
.

```
protected void Button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPList myList = currentSite.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("SharePointDatabase");

    try
    {
        if (myList != null && FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile != null && FileUpload_Pic.HasFile)
        {
            SPListItem listItem = myList.Items.Add();

            listItem["Title"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
            listItem["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNum.Text;
            listItem["Color"] = TextBox_Color.Text;
            listItem["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPrice.Text;
            listItem["MoreInformation"] = TextBox_MoreInfo.Text;

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.FileName);
            listItem["Image"] = fileName;

            listItem.Update();                                            

            TextBox_Search.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_Name.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_MoreInfo.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ProdNum.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_Color.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox_ListPrice.Text = string.Empty;

            Label_Exception.Text = "Saved to Database list.";

            Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Label_Exception.Text = x.Message;
    }

}
```

Comment: any exception u may able to wite

Answer (score 1):

You can add file as stream directly from File Upload to specific web using following method and then add the file path to the list as shown in below example,

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add(String.Concat(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.RootWeb.Url, path), stream, true);
```

path is relative path for the image. *in user case file name.*
stream can get using `FileUpload.FileContent` in file upload control

Then add this path to the list as below.

```
listItem["Image"] = path;
```

*This is work for all the browsers.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the SPList has Atachment Upload enabled?

I had made the expierience that the normal ribbon button isn't greyed out although the list is not able to hold itemattachments.

```
SPList list = new SPList(); // Sample
list.EnableAttachments = false; //set
bool attachmentsAllowed = list.EnableAttachments; //get
```

What Type of field is "Image"? It's not the attachments folder...

An other way to save your Image is to upload it to a library and use a "Hyperlink" field.

Use this as help: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/10/code-practices-gettingsetting-values.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49481/exception-when-adding-attachment/49485

There are some problems, when you are using FileUpload control in standard edit/add pages.